# How is 鎗 different from 槍 and 鑓?

Tags: kanji

**Edit**: This question has been reworded as much as possible from the original to try to make it a question about Japanese. Also, adding the IME単漢字辞書 fixed the IME problem (thanks to Tsuyoshi Ito for pointing that out). Quote about 単漢字辞書: `Microsoft IME単漢字辞書には、マクロソフトで読みが確認できたJIS第三・第四水準漢字が登録されています`. However, it looks like 鎗 is part of JIS第一水準漢字, so I still don't understand that part.

If I [look in the dictionary](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch/0/0na/18615800/), やり has three versions: 槍／鎗／鑓 (I understand they are not standard).

When I type やり, my windows IME shows me the following:

[image]

**Question**

Why is 鎗 not on the list? It seems 鎗 is considered to be different than 槍 and 鑓. What is special about the character 鎗?

**CLARIFICATION ON ENCODINGS AND IME DICTIONARIES**

MS IMEs 標準辞書 is based on jis x 0208 which includes JIS第1水準漢字 and JIS第2水準漢字. 鎗 is part of JIS第1水準 and this is why it comes out why you type そう with the default dictionary on MS IME. 単漢字辞書 is a separate dictionary based on JIS X 0213 which includes 第3水準漢字 and 第4水準漢字, if you add it, it shows 鎗 in the 変換リスト when you type やり. Now, why exactly this behavior occurs to me is a mystery (perhaps its just a bug), but I know that other dictionaries for other non-microsoft IMEs do not exhibit this behavior. I am assuming this is because they include all characters in the BMP and do not divide things up according to shift-jis taxonomy. Also, perhaps the dictionary implementors decided that 鎗 is 異体字, so they left it out.

Comment: You could turn this into a question about Japanese, by asking about the differences in usage for the three characters. In its current form, the question seems to be more suited for a different (computing related) SE site.

Comment: @user1205935: edited.

Comment: It appears as the third result in my OSX 10.7.3 IME.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. After the answers by everyone, maybe a difference in meaning gives little insight into why _your_ IME seems to be missing one of the characters. I'm using ibus/anthy IME on ubuntu and やり has all three characters you quote...

Comment: @user1205935: My guess is that it's just old (xp), but I was surprised googles ime had the same problem.

Comment: Candidate 7 in the screenshot says 単漢字 (single kanji letters).  If you choose it, rarer kanji letters are added to the candidate list, including 鎗 (at least in the version I use: Microsoft Office IME 2010).  But this is a question about the usage of MS IME, not a question about Japanese.

Comment: Shift-JIS is an encoding of a character set, and it does not specify readings of kanji letters.

Comment: I am sorry for not being helpful for you.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: I complete rewrote a description of what Im talking about in my answer. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get another IME. "鎗" was the *second* choice of my suggestion list, 槍 being the first one. I use "skk" via ibus for my IME. The reason it is not in your list is that you assumed that your IME would be exhaustive, and I don't think any IME would ever claim that.

As far as the difference is concerned, just looking at the radicals, I'd say the difference is what the spear is made of: wood, iron, or something else.

Comment: I use an Apple: "鎗" was also the second choice of my suggestion list & 槍 the first.

Comment: Thanks, I switched to [Baidu IME](http://ime.baidu.jp/type/) to solve my problem. It looks like ibus is only on linux, it's my work computer and I'm stuck with windows xp.

Answer (score 0):

As Axioplase already mentions, if you look at the radicals, you can divide the characters into two groups:

1. 槍: Made of wood.
2. 鎗／鑓: Made of metal.

Now, 鑓 is what is known as 国字 and did not originate from China. Also, in current Chinese, 鎗 usually refers to a  "rifle" or "gun" and not "spear" (however, the meaning of spear is still present) ([Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9397/index.htm) defines it as "rifle, small arms, hand gun" which is kind of amusing). In Japanese, 槍 and 鎗 both mean spear (with the difference being the material it is made from), however if you consider 鎗 as an 異体字, then is most common 槍. Also, 鎗 also has the meaning of "container", etc. (see below) and you can see it in words like [鎗金](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%8E%97%E9%87%91).

**References**

[【鎗/枪】ライフル](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2131214811632309101/2132629349332010503)

[異体字の認定](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%97%E4%BD%93#.E7.95.B0.E4.BD.93.E5.AD.97.E3.81.AE.E8.AA.8D.E5.AE.9A)

[槍/鑓/鎗・・・ヤリ](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1416896054)

[鎗と槍の違い 使い分けを教えて下さい｡](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1433095409)

[From here](http://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/kmr_tds/43633782.html):

> 鎗　ソウ　やり
>
> 解字：形声。倉が音を表わし、金属のふれ合う音声を表わす。
> 字義：
>
> ①なべ。三本足があるなべ。 　　(Type of pot, one with 3 legs)
>
> ②やり。(spear)
>
> ③こう（金偏に堅）鎗は、金属や石のふれる音。 　　(Sound of metal, rocks hitting together)
>
> ④長鎗は、米の別名。 　　(長鎗 is another name for 米)
>
> ⑤酒を入れる器。(Container for 酒)